# Equally Spaced Multiple Element Android Layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to get a layout of 8 round buttons in two columns that will respect the size of the buttons and nicely change in portrait or landscape mode.

I started out trying a GridLayout which absolutely didn't work.  I then tried two LinearLayouts but it seems you can't have multiple LinearLayouts at the root (I'm VERY new to Android btw).

The attempt I have at the moment is using a TableLayout but this doesn't seem to play nicely with the content.  The buttons are stretched to fill each cell and not respecting the explicit sizes set on each element.  Also the table isn't stretching vertically to fill the available space.

The code I have at the moment is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:stretchColumns="0,1">
    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <Button
            style="@style/button_text"
            android:layout_width="100sp"
            android:layout_height="100sp"
            android:background="@drawable/homebutton"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="Button1"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:isScrollContainer="true" />
        <Button
            style="@style/button_text"
            android:layout_width="100sp"
            android:layout_height="100sp"
            android:background="@drawable/homebutton"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="Button2"
            android:textColor="#fff" />
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <Button
            style="@style/button_text"
            android:layout_width="100sp"
            android:layout_height="100sp"
            android:background="@drawable/homebutton"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="Button3"
            android:textColor="#fff" />
        <Button
            style="@style/button_text"
            android:layout_width="100sp"
            android:layout_height="100sp"
            android:background="@drawable/homebutton"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="Button4"
            android:textColor="#fff" />
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <Button
            style="@style/button_text"
            android:layout_width="100sp"
            android:layout_height="100sp"
            android:background="@drawable/homebutton"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="Button5"
            android:textColor="#fff" />
        <Button
            style="@style/button_text"
            android:layout_width="100sp"
            android:layout_height="100sp"
            android:background="@drawable/homebutton"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="Button6"
            android:textColor="#fff" />
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <Button
            style="@style/button_text"
            android:layout_width="100sp"
            android:layout_height="100sp"
            android:background="@drawable/homebutton"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="Button7"
            android:textColor="#fff" />
        <Button
            style="@style/button_text"
            android:layout_width="100sp"
            android:layout_height="100sp"
            android:background="@drawable/homebutton"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="Button8"
            android:textColor="#fff" />
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

What I want to achieve is this in vertical orientation:

[image]

And this is landscape:

[image]

Proving to be a little elusive as to how best to get this layout working.

Comment: You can't have multiple LinearLayouts at the root, but you can put multiple LinearLayout in another layout (LinearLayout, RelativeLayout etc.).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first part of your question, is how to set up these circles so that they're evenly spaced on every device.

We'll use a root `LinearLayout` with two child `LinearLayout`'s weighted equally horizontally. Within those child layouts, you'll create 4 more `LinearLayout`'s weighted equally vertically. This cuts up the screen real estate to an even 2x4. Throw a button into each of those, and we acheive the layout we want:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <Button
                style="@style/button_text"
                android:layout_width="100sp"
                android:layout_height="100sp"
                android:background="@drawable/homebutton"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:isScrollContainer="true"
                android:text="Button1"
                android:textColor="#fff"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <Button
                style="@style/button_text"
                android:layout_width="100sp"
                android:layout_height="100sp"
                android:background="@drawable/homebutton"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:isScrollContainer="true"
                android:text="Button1"
                android:textColor="#fff"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <Button
                style="@style/button_text"
                android:layout_width="100sp"
                android:layout_height="100sp"
                android:background="@drawable/homebutton"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:isScrollContainer="true"
                android:text="Button1"
                android:textColor="#fff"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <Button
                style="@style/button_text"
                android:layout_width="100sp"
                android:layout_height="100sp"
                android:background="@drawable/homebutton"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:isScrollContainer="true"
                android:text="Button1"
                android:textColor="#fff"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <Button
                style="@style/button_text"
                android:layout_width="100sp"
                android:layout_height="100sp"
                android:background="@drawable/homebutton"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:isScrollContainer="true"
                android:text="Button1"
                android:textColor="#fff"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <Button
                style="@style/button_text"
                android:layout_width="100sp"
                android:layout_height="100sp"
                android:background="@drawable/homebutton"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:isScrollContainer="true"
                android:text="Button1"
                android:textColor="#fff"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <Button
                style="@style/button_text"
                android:layout_width="100sp"
                android:layout_height="100sp"
                android:background="@drawable/homebutton"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:isScrollContainer="true"
                android:text="Button1"
                android:textColor="#fff"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <Button
                style="@style/button_text"
                android:layout_width="100sp"
                android:layout_height="100sp"
                android:background="@drawable/homebutton"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:isScrollContainer="true"
                android:text="Button1"
                android:textColor="#fff"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Now that we've completed the portrait version, you'll have to slightly restructure a duplicate version of the layout - to use specifically when a device is in landscape orientation. I will not complete that version for you - as that should be easy to figure out with the above code; however, here's a resource on where to put your landscape layout when you're done. - [Orientation-Specific Layouts](http://www.androidpeople.com/android-portrait-amp-landscape-differeent-layouts)

Comment: I'm really struggling to get this landscape orientation version done, my Visual Studio IDE keeps doing random things which isn't helping.  Do you have any good resources / tools you'd recommend for learning?

Comment: Thanks for the help BTW certainly got me going in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Example layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="100sp"
            android:layout_height="100sp"
            android:background="@drawable/abc_btn_radio_to_on_mtrl_000"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:isScrollContainer="true"
            android:textColor="#fff" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="100sp"
            android:layout_height="100sp"
            android:background="@drawable/abc_btn_radio_to_on_mtrl_000"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:isScrollContainer="true"
            android:textColor="#fff" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="100sp"
            android:layout_height="100sp"
            android:background="@drawable/abc_btn_radio_to_on_mtrl_000"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:isScrollContainer="true"
            android:textColor="#fff" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="100sp"
            android:layout_height="100sp"
            android:background="@drawable/abc_btn_radio_to_on_mtrl_000"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:isScrollContainer="true"
            android:textColor="#fff" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="100sp"
            android:layout_height="100sp"
            android:background="@drawable/abc_btn_radio_to_on_mtrl_000"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:isScrollContainer="true"
            android:textColor="#fff" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="100sp"
            android:layout_height="100sp"
            android:background="@drawable/abc_btn_radio_to_on_mtrl_000"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:isScrollContainer="true"
            android:textColor="#fff" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="100sp"
            android:layout_height="100sp"
            android:background="@drawable/abc_btn_radio_to_on_mtrl_000"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:isScrollContainer="true"
            android:textColor="#fff" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="100sp"
            android:layout_height="100sp"
            android:background="@drawable/abc_btn_radio_to_on_mtrl_000"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:isScrollContainer="true"
            android:textColor="#fff" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Example code to put in Overrided method `OnCreateView`, which will change orientation for your layouts:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
    final LinearLayout linearLayout1 = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.linearLayout1);
    final LinearLayout linearLayout2 = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.linearLayout2);
    final LinearLayout linearLayout3 = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.linearLayout3);

    final int currentOrientation = getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;
    if (currentOrientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
        linearLayout1.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        linearLayout2.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
        linearLayout3.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
    }
    else {
        linearLayout1.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
        linearLayout2.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        linearLayout3.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    }
    return view;
}
```

Comment: This is interesting.  In most situations I like to avoid code in views (I'm using Xamarin and MvvmCross) but seeing that this would result in only one layout file this is less markup to author and manage.  Does this still work dynamically when the user changes orientation on the fly?

Comment: Yes, it works. I checked it. Every time user rotate device, it switches orientation for layouts.

Answer (score 0):

I want to recommend approach where you use one horizontal oriented LinearLayout with weight as much as how many views you wish and inside that you put as many RelativeLayouts as you put weight number. In code, it should be like that:

```
<LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/mealLinearLayout"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@id/addNewMealButton"
                        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"

                        android:weightSum="4">

                        <RelativeLayout
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_weight="1">

                            <ImageButton
                                android:id="@+id/breakfastImageButton"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                                android:background="@drawable/bigcircle" />
                        </RelativeLayout>

                        <RelativeLayout
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_weight="1">

                            <ImageButton
                                android:id="@+id/lunchImageButton"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                                android:background="@drawable/bigcircle" />
                        </RelativeLayout>

                        <RelativeLayout
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_weight="1">

                            <ImageButton
                                android:id="@+id/dinnerImageButton"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                                android:background="@drawable/bigcircle" />
                        </RelativeLayout>

                        <RelativeLayout
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_weight="1">

                            <ImageButton
                                android:id="@+id/favoriteImageButton"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                                android:background="@drawable/bigcircle" />
                        </RelativeLayout>

 </LinearLayout>
```